# Render a PHP array as a table in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an array in PHP with this structure

```
$array = array(
   'head1' => array(1,2,3),
   'head2' => array(4,5,6),
   'head3' => array(7,8,9),
);
```

How can I create an HTML table in twig which have this structure where every array of the $array variable is a column and array keys are table headers?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head2</th>
    <th>head3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the builtin filter [`keys`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/keys.html). If it's not exactly what you expected, then it is because your array needs to be processed in PHP before passing it to twig

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    {% for key in array|keys %}
        <th>{{ key }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for sub_array in array %}
        <tr>
        {% for value in sub_array %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You say that I have to convert columns arrays in rows array?

Comment: Yes, as you won't be able to do it easily in twig