# Convert php array to table with twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig

Hi I need to build a table with twig from a php array, I would like to use the array keys as header for each column.

this is the array

```
    Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
         [building_code] => 2C 
         [building_unit_id] => 57 
         [address] => Via monteverde 45 
         [name] => Andrea 
     ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
         [building_code] => 4E 
         [building_unit_id] => 55 
         [address] => Via monteverde 45 
         [name] => Andrea 
     ) 
    )
```

**This is what I've tried so far**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>

            {% for titolo in prova|keys %}

            <th>{{titolo}}</th>

            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for sub_array in prova %}
        <tr>
            {% for value in sub_array %}
            <td>{{ value }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is the result**

```
0   1
2C  57  Via monteverde 45   Andrea
4E  55  Via monteverde 45   Andrea
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What you describe sounds good. The next step for you is to take a look at the documentation of the tool you want to use. And maybe at a few examples you can find online. And then you start.

Comment: You want to use array keys as column headers?

Comment: Hi @VinayPatil yes this is what I want

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51910401/1483629

Comment: Hi @VinayPatil yes I've come across that post and that is what I've tried. I edited the question with what I've tried and also the result I get

Comment: Hi @Qirel I've edited the question to explain what I've tried

Comment: I'm not really familiar with twig, but try to loop `{% for titolo in prova.0|keys %}` instead. You need to get the first element, then loop the keys of that (not the keys of the outer array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the keys you want to use as headers exist as the keys in the second-depth array, not the primary array. Meaning that you have to loop those keys instead of the keys in the first array.

Using `prova.0` to get the first element, will then result in the `keys` being of the sub-array - which you can then loop as before.

```
{% for titolo in prova|first|keys %}
    <th>{{titolo}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi @Qirel many thanks it works, accepted your answer because you also explained whay my code wasn't working and I've learnt something knew thanks to you

Comment: Consider using `prova | first | keys` over `prova.0 | keys` though

Comment: I actually had that first, but wasn't sure if you could do it like that way, so I edited it to what I knew would work - I'm not that familiar with twig. Good to know that `prova|first|keys` would work too!

Comment: Yeah, it's safer to use as the key `0` maybe doesn't exist.

Comment: You're absolutley right, I just wasn't 100% sure if it was allowed syntax in twig :-) Thanks, DarkBee!

Comment: Thanks guys, I found that twig documentation doesn’t explain well the use of first or maybe it was me that couldn’t find it

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this by fetching keys of the first array of `prova`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for titolo in prova.0|keys %}
                <th>{{titolo}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for sub_array in prova %}
            <tr>
                {% for value in sub_array %}
                    <td>{{ value }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```